# React Router V6 Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I currently have my app as follows with my routes wrapped  inside of BrowserRouter and I am receiving

> Uncaught Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`

Below is my codesandbox

I did a

> ctl + F + Shift

and only have 1 router in my app. Does anyone see a syntax error or have a suggestion?
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/dangolbeeker/Sandbox44/draft/wispy-bird?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9lydpst004llri6gj5s9usn%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9lydseo000k2869y6itb842%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9lyeeyy007r2869gdz4etbc%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9lyedds005t2869rxlkm3z3%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)

Here is my App component:

```jsx
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Features from "./components/body/Features/FeaturesGrid/FeaturesGrid";
import Artists from "./components/body/Artists/Artists";
import Fans from "./components/body/Fans/Fans";
import Groups from "./components/body/Groups/Groups";
import Footer from "./components/body/Footer/Footer";
import PPV from "./components/body/PPV/PPV";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav>
        <Header />
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/features" element={<Features />} />
        <Route path="/artists" element={<Artists />} />
        <Route path="/fans" element={<Fans />} />
        <Route path="/groups" element={<Groups />} />
        <Route path="/ppv" element={<PPV />} />
        {/* <Route path="/feed" element={<Feed />} /> */}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Header component:

```jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import HeaderCSS from "../Header/Header.module.css";
import Menu from "../../svgs/bars-solid.svg";
import Close from "../../svgs/times-solid.svg";
import Logo from "../../svgs/logotrans.svg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Header() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenu(!menu);
  };

  const styleMenu = {
    left: menu ? 0 : "-100%",
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <div className={HeaderCSS.menu} onClick={toggleMenu}>
        <img src={Menu} alt="" width="30" />
      </div>

      <div className="logo">
        <img src={Logo} all="" width="120" height="90" />
      </div>
      <div className={HeaderCSS.nav_container}>
        <ul style={styleMenu}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/features">Features</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/artists">Artists</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/fans">Fans</Link>/
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/groups">Groups</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/ppv">PPV</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/feed">Feed</Link>
          </li>
          <li onClick={toggleMenu}>
            <img src={Close} alt="" width="30" className="menu" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Why are you importing `Router` in `App`? You're not using it here but are you sure your actual code doesn't?

Comment: could you push your most recent changes, I think the changes that are currently there have some stuff missing

Comment: fatcat32, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering `App` recursively

```
<Route path="/" element={<App />} />
```

You can't do that

Replace `App` with another component

```
<Route path="/" element={<div />} />
```